# Hibernate + JSF2 Session Is Closed

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I am getting session closed exception in my JSF + Hibernate Application when adding a new country. Here is the code for your reference

**country.xhtml**

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{country.getPreRequisites}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Above code populates the countries Map to be used below. If I remove f:metadata block then i can add country and won't get session is closed message.

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{country.countryId}" id="countryId" columns="4" style="width: 700px" layout="grid">
      <f:selectItems value="#{country.countries}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

**CountryManagedBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "country")
@ViewScoped
public class CountryManagedBean
{
   public String saveCountry()
   {
      String actionFlag="country";
      FacesMessage message=null;
      try
      {
        int flag=countryDao.saveCountry(this);
        if(flag==1)
        {
            message=new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Country","Saved Successfully");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE, "CountryManagedBean","saveCountry", "Saving Country Failed", e);
    }
    return actionFlag;
  }

   public void getPreRequisites(ComponentSystemEvent event)
  {
      FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     if (!fc.isPostback())    //Page Is Called / Rendered
     {
         countryDao.getPreRequisites(this); 
     }
  }
}
```

**CountryDao.java**

```
public class CountryDao
{

   Session session = null;
   Transaction tx=null;

   public void getPreRequisites(CountryManagedBean country)
   {
       try
      {
          tx=session.beginTransaction();
         Criteria cr=session.createCriteria(CountryPojo.class)
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("countryId"),"countryId")
            .add(Projections.property("countryName"),"countryName")
            .add(Projections.property("countryShortCode"),"countryShortCode")
            )
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CountryPojo.class));
        List<CountryPojo> countryList=cr.list();
        System.out.println("Total Countries Found:"+countryList.size());
        for(CountryPojo pojo:countryList)
        {
            country.getCountries().put(pojo.getCountryName()+" ["+pojo.getCountryShortCode()+"]",pojo.getCountryId());
        }
        CountryPojo p=countryList.get(0);
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%% Country Id:"+p.getCountryId()+"\t############# Country Name:"+p.getCountryName());
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e)
    {
        LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE, "Country Dao", "getPreRequisites","Caught HibernateException while getting pre requisites",e);
        try
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex)
        {
            LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE,"CountryDao","getPreRequisites","Caught HibernateException while rolling back transaction",ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
public int saveCountry(CountryManagedBean country)
{
    int flag=-1;
    try
    {
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
        CountryPojo countryPojo=new CountryPojo(country.getCountryName(),country.getCountryShortCode(),country.getLastUpdateBy());
        country.setCountryId((Integer)session.save(countryPojo));
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Country {0} Saved With Id {1}", new Object[]{country.getCountryName(), country.getCountryId()});
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e)
    {
        LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE, "Country Dao", "saveCountry","Caught HibernateException while saving country",e);
        try
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex)
        {
            LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE,"CountryDao","saveCountry","Caught HibernateException while rolling back transaction",ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return flag;
}
public CountryDao()
{
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CountryDao.class.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing this because your JPA/Hibernate session is closed by the time your JSF calls `getPreRequisites`. You'll need to add this to your web.xml to keep the session open so that the view can load your lazy loaded objects.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I am not using spring framework. I am not getting an exception while calling `getPreRequisites` but after the page is rendered at the time of adding a new country i am getting the excpetion. But If I removed the call to `getPreRequisites` every thing works fine. I searched on net found this is something related to thread as I had set `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `thread` as found in examples. Can you please help in understanding as I am not comfortable with Threads.